# Cloning Git repo in MacOs returns permission denied

Tags: macos, github, cloning

```
/Users/Justin/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/MyRepo git clone https://github.com/Bizcochoo/RDomm.git
```

zsh: permission denied: /Users/Justin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/MyRepo

I need help !!! thanks! btw using macOS Catalina

Comment: Permission denied. Have you configured git such that its auth'ing with a user? Do you have write permissions to that dir?

Comment: How would that look like?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.